# How to aggregate objects from a QuerySet

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a Django model User which has a one-way self referencing many-to-many relationship:

```
following = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='Following', symmetrical=False, related_name='following_user')
```

I've got another model for Comment which has a relationship to User:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I would like to get all comments of following users. How do I get all comments from a QuerySet of Users?
Something like this?:

```
self.following.[somehow get all comments]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that ended up working for me:

```
Comment.objects.filter(user__in=self.get_following())
```

Answer (score 2):

With queries like this, you need to turn it around: you want comments, so start with the Comment model.

```
Comment.objects.filter(user__following=self)
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this since I'm trying to compare the comment to many users rather than one (and if it's there, I'm not seeing it in your code). Would something like `Comment.objects.filter(user=self.following)` work? implying that any match would make the filter true? Sorry if I'm being dense. I'm new to this. :)